# I/AssistStructure( 2706): Flattened final assist data: 460 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views

Tags: flutter

I make home screen in flutter where I have drawer, and 2 items in drawer menu where it opens alert dialog. In these 2 items I have 2 text fields, when I click on text field I got error `I/AssistStructure( 2706): Flattened final assist data: 460 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views`.
What can cause this error,I tried to google it but I haven't found solution for it. Any help will be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I write textformfield instead of textfield my error get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly that error when the **widgets** are **implemented incorrectly**.Check your textflied and if you using Third-Party Dependencies then it's must be up-to-date